# Doing a lookup using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value (variant) `strCompany` in my workbook.  I would like to determine if this value exists in column A of another workbook, tmp_workbook.  If it does not exist there should be a message box. Does the following code make sense (I define the variables tmp_workbook and strCompany earlier in my code)?  If not perhaps you can suggest a better way?

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set value_exists_in_table = tmp_workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100000").Find(strCompany)

    ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
            Case 9, 91
                MsgBox "The company " & strCompany & " was not found."
            Exit Sub

    End Select
```

Comment: Arjun, could you elaborate on your problem? Where are you having difficulties? I suggest using the documentation as well. The documentation for the Range.Find method [states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839746.aspx) that Find retuns `Nothing` if no match is found. Otherwise, it returns "the first cell where that information is found"

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) inherits many parameters from the last time it was used; commonly by the user on the worksheet. You should explicitly specify several more commonly used parameters like `LookAt:xlWhole` or `LookAt:xlPart` and `LookIn:=xlValues` or `LookIn:=xlFormulas`.

I typically stay away from .Find for exact matches in a single row or column. The [Excel Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) object's native [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) does an excellent job of locating a value.

```
dim rw as variant
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    rw = application.match(strCompany, .Columns(1), 0)
    if not iserror(rw) then
        value_exists_in_table = .cells(rw, 1).value
        debug.print value_exists_in_table & " found in row " & rw
    else
        debug.print "The company " & strCompany & " was not found."
    end if
end with
```